# Sony Vegas 12 Not Rendering Parts Of Video

Tags: video, audio

Using Sony Vegas Pro 12 and i am rendering a video. However the rendered video hasn't got any audio and some video parts are black. I am using a some transitions and i am currently trying to fix the video however the audio isn't there completely.